# Why are changes to the Winlogon registry being ignored by MDT TaskSequence?

Tags: windows, mdt

I'm setting up a Task Sequence(TS) in MDT for deploying Win10 IoT Enterprise. As one of the final steps in the TS I'm trying to add AutoLogon of the user account to the registry. But when the TS finishes and I check, the changes have either not been made or they have been reset by some clean-up script.

I create a new "Run Command Line" step in the TS, right after the Install Applications step that MDT generates automatically. This step runs a script I've added to the Deploy/Scripts folder. I get no errors here, but no result either.

I've tried to export the correct registry-settings to a .reg file and use the "Run Command Line" step to import these. Again, no errors and no result.

I've moved both of these steps down in the list, so that they are the last thing the TS does. Again, no errors and no result.

```
cmd /c reg add "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /v AutoAdminLogon /t REG_SZ /d 1 /f
cmd /c reg add "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /v DefaultUserName /t REG_SZ /d <username>/f
cmd /c reg add "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /v DefaultDomainName /t REG_SZ /d <Domain> /f
cmd /c reg add "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /v DefaultPassword /t REG_SZ /d <password> /f
cmd /c reg add "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /v AutoLogonCount /t REG_DWORD /d 500000 /f
```

I want the AutoLogon to be set automatically. If not, there has to be a procedure for how to set it up and that not only feels unnecessary, but is also a source of errors if its forgotten.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the registry-changes work fine if I add them after the Task Sequence has finished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more googling I finally found:

https://ccmcache.wordpress.com/2018/02/07/workaround-for-windows-10-1709-autoadminlogon-at-the-end-of-configmgr-osd-task-sequence/

Where there is a solution. An ugly one, but the only way I've found that works. So thank you to the author of this.